# Kernel preemption on same priority tasks

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling

Can someone help me understand with clear explantion or any reference link, How kernel handles preemption on tasks having same priority. Suppose i have three TASKS A, B and C assigned with High priority

TASK(A)
{
 High Priority
 Reading Asynchronous messages
}

TASK(B)
{
 High Priority
 Sending Asynchronous messages
}

TASK(C)
{
 High Priority
 Draw process
}

In this case which Task will be considered for processing and how is it preempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General scheduling order is

1. Kernel invokes function `schedule()` either directly in kernel context or when `TIF_NEED_RESCHED` flag is set and kernel returning from interrupt context.
2. This function invokes `pick_next_task()` to receive the task, which will preempt currently running one.
3. `pick_next_task()` invokes every scheduler class' `pick_next_task()` in order of descending priority until one of them returns task. Note, that priority means class' priority (e.g. soft real-time or normal), not process' one.
4. The CFS's approach (scheduler for normal processes) is to give each process an equal amount of *virtual run-time*. Virtual run-time is a process' real run-time weighted with its priority (process' priority). So CFS class returns task with lesser virtual runtime.

For scheduler, there is no matter what process are doing, what massages it sends or receives. So, in general case, if your processes have equal priorities, process with less run-time will preempt another process on the next `schedule()` invokation.

Comment: Thanks rasen. How does CFS evaluate process's virtual runtime. does it depend on the resourced used by the process. I want to understand this selection criteria by CFS to findout process virtual runtime

Comment: Another two points :) 1) Does it mean the priority assigned by user will not considered for Task selection 2) Is it ideally possible for two tasks to have same virtual runtime

Comment: 0. Runtime depends only on amount of processor time, process running. It is increased in timer interrupt handler.
1. Process priority used as a weight for real runtime. So, processes with higher priority will get higher real runtime.
2. Yes, it is possible. In this case, scheduler can pick any of them.

Comment: CFS schedular mentions this USER_Priority, NICE_VALUE and task's rt_priority how are these related? So finally derived (minimum)vruntime is what considered for the task schedulding is it?

Comment: I don't know, what USER_Priority is. Nice value, also known as niceness, is a value in range of -20..19. Greater value means lesser prioriry. Only root permited to set negative values. rt_priority is real-time priority. For real-time processes this is a value in range 0..100. For non real-time processes, niceness is mapped directly in range 101..140 of rt_priority. CFS schedules non-realtime processes.  I can advice you to read something about scheduling. Robert Love provides a good chapter on this topic in Linux Kernel Development.

Comment: Thanks rasen for your paitence answering my queries will take some off reading these manuals first.